# Changing the appearance of equation numbers with amsmath

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, formatting, amsmath

For equations in my document, I use the facilities of the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. In order to make the equation numbers  more eye-catching, I want them to be in boldface and a little bit indented to the right, i.e. like this:

[image: comparison of default and desired output]

I've already tried redefining the internal `amsmath` macros `\maketag@@@` or `\tagform@`. But both

```
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\bfseries#1\hspace{3mm}}}
```

and

```
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\hspace{3mm}}
```

also change the references produced by `\eqref`, as this macro internally uses `\tagform@` to produce its output. These references should keep their default appearance, however, as I don't need the prominent formatting in the running text.

The most promising approach I've tried so far is to redefine `\print@eqnum`:

```
\def\mytagform#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\hspace{3mm}}
\def\print@eqnum{\mytagform\theequation}
```

This redefinition doesn't affect the `\eqref` references. Sadly though, it seems to work only with `align` environments, the tags of `equation` environments aren't changed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
% \maketag@@@ and \tagform@ also influence \eqref
% \def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\bfseries#1\hspace{3mm}}}
% \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\hspace{3mm}}

% \print@eqnum looks promising, but applies only to align environments
\def\mytagform#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\hspace{3mm}}
\def\print@eqnum{\mytagform\theequation}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2\label{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
    1+1 &= 2\label{align}
\end{align}
\eqref{equation}, \eqref{align}
\end{document}
```

outputs
[image]

**How can I change the appearance of equation numbers without affecting references produced by `\eqref`?**

Comment: The timely juxtaposition of this and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28894/86 makes me ponder the potentiality of a package here ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at the code, I can see lots of places where `\tagform@` is used and presumably the code for `equation` uses one explicitly instead of `\print@eqnum`.  Guessing completely here, I would say that `\print@eqnum` is used when amsmath has to read in the whole equation and typeset it out again carefully (to get the alignment right).  Since `equation` doesn't involve any fancy alignment, it can be processed directly and as a consequence the tag is written using `\tagform@` directly.

How about going for the opposite direction?  Modify `\tagform@` to be what you want it to be and then change `\eqref` so that it uses the original.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\hspace{3mm}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\mytagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2\label{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
    1+1 &= 2\label{align}
\end{align}
\eqref{equation}, \eqref{align}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: ams tags changed]

(Note added in edit: Barbara Beeton has asked me to add a comment to the effect that the AMS redefinition of the `equation` environment is meant to keep it looking as the original but with a check for if the `\qed` symbol should be added.  Also, `eqnarray` appears to be a bit of a minefield in its definition so Things May Go Wrong if you use `eqnarray`!)

Comment: This shows a weakness of **amsmath**: the same command `\tagform@` is used for two *distinct* purposes; it's true that frequently the appearance of the equation number is the same, but this can't be taken for granted. Maybe splitting it into `\eqtagform@` and `\reftagform@` would help class and package writers.

Comment: Is there a way to restore to the default setting, let us say outside a `\newenvironment`?

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to restore to the default setting, let us say outside a \newenvironment or after some point in the document?

Comment: @azetina Yes, of course, but it's quite difficult to understand what you have in mind.

Comment: @egreg I will post it as a new question?

Comment: @azetina It's probably better

Comment: @egreg see [Adjust equation numbering relative to a \newenvironment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57465/10898).

Comment: Only slightly related, but as @Andrew Stacey pointed out, `eqnarray` is not always the best choice: “[Avoid eqnarray!](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf)” by *Lars Madsen* gives some more reasons. (Should this be required reading?)