# Is it possible to move an equation number in the equation environment?

Tags: equations, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the apperance of equation numbers with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/changing-the-apperance-of-equation-numbers-with-amsmath)

I would like to move an equation number from its default position a little bit left.

(I learned to move an equation a little bit left from this site. But I could not locate any reference to move the equation number a little bit left. I searched this site with     "move equation number".)

The following is the code that I am using.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\hspace{-9cm}a_1+d_1=47
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Edited Question:

How can I align both equations and the equation numbers in the following code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter

\def\mytagform#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\hspace{3cm}}
\def\print@eqnum{\mytagform\theequation}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:eq1}
\hspace{-6cm}a_1+7d=47
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\label{eq2}
\hspace{-6cm}a_1+20d=112
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, see the question I linked in my edit; it should have all the necessary information. If not, please be more specific in your question.

Comment: @egreg  Thank you.  That reference is enough for me to move on.  I do not understand how it works (yet) but I used your (new) align environment (instead of the equation environment) to get the desired effect.

Comment: It's hard to understand the role of `\hskip{-6cm}` in that code. If you want "left aligned" equations, consider the `fleqn` option to **amsmath**.

Comment: If you remove the `\hspace{-6cm}` the equation numbers will be aligned.

Comment: I wanted to move an equation few cms (say 6 cms) to left and then reduce the gap between the equation and the equation number by a different amount (say 3 cms).  I still do not have a solution.  However, as I mentioned, I am playing with Andrew Stacey's answer to the question referred by egreg.  Thanks to everyone who made comments.  I truly appreciate this site.

Comment: @Sony: have you considered using, for example, a `minipage` and one of the subsidiary environments (`gathered`, `aligned`, or `alignedat`) from `amsmath`?

Comment: As you seem to have found something that works via that other question, I've cast the last vote to close this as a duplicate of that one.  If there's something that you can't figure out, please do post a new question explaining what you tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer to the edited question would be to use `\mathrlap` from the [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), together with a `\phantom` to obtain the correct horizontal alignment:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
...
\hspace{-6cm}\mathrlap{a_1+7d=47}\phantom{a_1+20d=112}
...
\hspace{-6cm}a_1+20d=112
```

[image: Correct alignment of equation numbers]

Regardless, as @egreg suggests in his comment, using `\hspace` for horizontal movement to some (arbitrary?) length of `-6cm` seems a bit bizarre.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I deleted the ``edited question" as I found a reasonable solution by using Andrew Stacey's solution to the question posted by egreg.  But your solution seems much nice.  Therefore, I retyped the ``edited question".  Sorry.