# Coloured equation number (without changing colour of reference using hyperref)

Tags: hyperref, equations, color

I am working on a file where I am using the package `hyperref` so that the references to equations are linked and coloured. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1=\beta\left[ \frac{ 1+\left( 1-\tau_{t+1}\right) r_{t} }{\Pi_{t+1}} \right]\label{Fisher}
\end{equation}

Make reference to \eqref{Fisher}.

\end{document}
```

This gives me the reference at the end red, which is great. Now I want to have the equation number in blue (not the reference to the equation, but the equation number itself). I achieve that by adding

```
\renewcommand\theequation{{\color{blue}\arabic{equation}}}
```

to the preamble, before of after `hyperref` (the result seems to be the same). On first compile, great, I get the exact result I want: the equation number is blue, and the reference to the equation is in red:

[image]

**but a second compile will turn both the equation number and the reference to the equation blue**!

How can I avoid that, and have my equation number in blue not interfere with the equation reference colour from hyperref?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can adapt [this answer by Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28907/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\reftagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces\textcolor{blue}{#1}\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\reftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1=\beta\left[ \frac{ 1+\left( 1-\tau_{t+1}\right) r_{t} }{\Pi_{t+1}} \right]\label{Fisher}
\end{equation}

Make reference to \eqref{Fisher}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, that works. I just wish I could do those things myself. Are the `\let`, `\tagform@`, etc commands part of LaTeX or are they TeX? Also, is the problem related to `amsmath` rather than `hyperref` as the link you provided seems to suggest?

Comment: @Vivi `\let` is a primitive TeX command: we save a copy of `\tagform@` (an internal of `amsmath`) before redefining it. As I commented there, it's a weakness of `amsmath` that uses the same command for two different purposes.