# colored equation numbers with breqn package?

Tags: equations, numbering, color, breqn

I was experimenting with the use of `breqn` for a few unwieldy formulas, but wonder how to maintain the equation number coloring I'd been using, based on the following questions:

[Changing the appearance of equation numbers with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/changing-the-apperance-of-equation-numbers-with-amsmath/28907#28907)

[Coloured equation number (without changing colour of reference using hyperref)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50521/coloured-equation-number-without-changing-colour-of-reference-using-hyperref)

The following sample shows the color'ing commands that I used based on answer text in the links above (which I don't understand, so am not able to modify)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{Red}(#1)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
s = 1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +10 +11 +12 +13 +14 +15 +16 +17
+18 +19 +20 +21 +22 +23 +24 +25 +26 +27 +28 +29 +30 +31 +32 +33
+34 +35 +36 +37 +38 +39 +40
\end{dmath}

\begin{equation}
a
=
b + c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

producing the following

[image: red color on equation. default color on dmath]

I see in the `breqn` docs that there is a `\eqnumcolor` variable, but am not sure how to use it for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand` in the preamble to change it:

```
\renewcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{red}}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{Red}(#1)}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
s = 1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +10 +11 +12 +13 +14 +15 +16 +17
+18 +19 +20 +21 +22 +23 +24 +25 +26 +27 +28 +29 +30 +31 +32 +33
+34 +35 +36 +37 +38 +39 +40
\end{dmath}

\begin{equation}
a
=
b + c
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```