# Put equation numbers in the sidemargin with Tufte-Latex class

Tags: equations, numbering, margins, tufte

In Tufte-Latex all captions etc. are in the side margin. I want to put the equation numbers there as well. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\def\a{One two three. }
\def\b{\a Five. \a Six seven eight. \a \a}
\def\c{\b\b\b\b}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\makeatletter

\let\orig@maketag@@@\maketag@@@
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\let\maketag@@@\orig@maketag@@@\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}

\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\rlap{\kern\marginparsep\m@th\normalfont#1}\kern1sp}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\b\b\b\marginpar{aaa}\b\b

\begin{figure}[h]
zzz
\caption{zz zz zz}
\end{figure}

bbb
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myequation}
    f(x)=x^2
\end{equation}
Test reference: \eqref{eq:myequation}

\c

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only tricky bit is the `\kern1sp` as a zero width tag seems to throw `amsmath` of course and it moves the number down as if there were not room for it on the line.

See also

[Changing the appearance of equation numbers with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/changing-the-apperance-of-equation-numbers-with-amsmath)

Comment: That's exactly what I want! The only thing you need to take care of by hand: marginnotes that are "too" long and cover the equation number.

Comment: Well that's harder to fix. You could make the equation numbers marginotes but then they would drift away from the equations. I do have an old half finished answer to a question on this site that implements a margin note mechanism that would allow equations to "block" parts of the margin area, but it involves re-writing large swathes of latex internals and doesn't work, so I don't recommend it:-)