# Equation numbers in outer margins on a two-sided document

Tags: equations, memoir, double-sided

I'm looking for a two-sided extension to the solution for this question:

[Put equation numbers in the sidemargin with Tufte-Latex class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65917/4483)

This post seems relevant:

[Equation tag in twoside-mode outer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26780/4483)

I tried playing around with `tagsleft@` without any luck. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass[openany,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\newcommand{\marginnote}[1]{\marginpar[\raggedleft#1]{\raggedright#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
Integer suscipit massa et nulla accumsan sed lacinia lacus tincidunt. Aenean nisi lacus, iaculis eu consequat in, fermentum eget urna. Proin augue lacus, euismod eu tempor vel, mollis eget quam. Donec vitae consequat nulla. In cursus sagittis diam, at tristique sem interdum pharetra.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{theorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\begin{proof}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Morbi gravida dapibus dapibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris mauris diam, faucibus vitae pretium vitae, volutpat eget velit. Aenean quis vestibulum ante. Duis enim tortor, accumsan eget hendrerit non, pellentesque vel magna. Duis eros turpis, auctor vel aliquam vitae, congue ut dolor.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Sed a libero mi. Donec cursus dignissim quam tincidunt fermentum. Curabitur ac libero leo, non sagittis nisi. Proin sodales tincidunt ante, in aliquam justo cursus in. Nunc tempus feugiat volutpat. Phasellus porttitor dolor elementum quam suscipit tempus. Donec posuere consectetur turpis sed congue. Sed et nunc dui, sit amet viverra erat. Ut malesuada molestie quam, porta fringilla libero consequat quis.
\begin{theorem}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\begin{proof}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Nullam elementum libero ut erat suscipit cursus non eget nibh. In accumsan rhoncus scelerisque. Sed vel eros et lacus tincidunt laoreet. Etiam molestie metus id tortor euismod vitae bibendum nisi rhoncus.

Pellentesque nec gravida ligula. Curabitur nibh sem, porta in suscipit non, porttitor lobortis arcu. Sed imperdiet, nisi sit amet vehicula lobortis, eros urna aliquam magna, sed auctor sem dui nec turpis. Nulla facilisi. Nam a elit lacus. Etiam vel leo ligula. Donec lectus mi, tristique at lobortis id, viverra nec felis.
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Etiam vel felis at enim pulvinar lacinia lacinia quis ipsum. Etiam ac elementum tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque sit amet rhoncus tortor.
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}

Nullam sollicitudin nisl ac metus malesuada fermentum. Mauris tellus arcu, porttitor et condimentum ut, commodo pellentesque justo. Nam rutrum, nunc non dictum placerat, dolor metus interdum dui, eu tincidunt libero mauris vel ante.
\begin{align}
  A &= \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\} \\
  A &= \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{align}
Nunc placerat auctor odio, vel ullamcorper massa dapibus eu. Suspendisse luctus, erat at semper pulvinar, velit diam convallis metus, vitae aliquam nibh tortor vitae neque. Morbi venenatis eleifend sapien at pulvinar. Quisque urna leo, molestie ut consequat id, porta vitae neque. Praesent varius convallis justo id tincidunt. Duis nulla elit, euismod sit amet tincidunt ut, sodales eu felis. Phasellus rutrum bibendum urna sit amet iaculis.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Nullam vel velit quis nibh volutpat ullamcorper. Pellentesque tempor turpis quis massa tincidunt imperdiet. Nam lobortis, justo quis mollis faucibus, erat enim lobortis massa, sagittis egestas lacus odio sed enim. Morbi pulvinar placerat sem, eget pulvinar risus hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed elementum faucibus mi, eget euismod magna convallis vel. Fusce egestas posuere dignissim.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updated to cope with `\chapter` and putting the numbers in the margin

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,standard]{ntheorem}

\newcommand{\marginnote}[1]{\marginpar[\raggedleft#1]{\raggedright#1}}



\makeatletter

\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\leavevmode%
%\pdfsavepos
%\edef\tmp{\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\EQ@\romannumeral#1{{\noexpand\the\c@page}{\noexpand\the\pdflastxpos}}}}%
\protected@edef\tmp{\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef\string\csname\space EQ@#1\string\endcsname{{\noexpand\the\c@page}{}}}}%
\tmp
\expandafter\ifx\csname EQ@#1\endcsname\relax
\else
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\foo\csname EQ@#1\endcsname{#1}%
\fi
}}

\def\foo#1#2#3{%
\ifodd\numexpr#1\relax
\kern1sp\rlap{\kern\marginparsep(\ignorespaces#3\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
\else
\kern1sp\llap{(\ignorespaces#3\unskip\@@italiccorr)\kern\dimexpr+\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax}%
\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}

TEST \ref{a} \ref{b}

\clearpage


TEST  \ref{a} \ref{b}


Integer suscipit massa et nulla accumsan sed lacinia lacus tincidunt. Aenean nisi lacus, iaculis eu consequat in, fermentum eget urna. Proin augue lacus, euismod eu tempor vel, mollis eget quam. Donec vitae consequat nulla. In cursus sagittis diam, at tristique sem interdum pharetra.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}\label{a}
      A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Morbi gravida dapibus dapibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris mauris diam, faucibus vitae pretium vitae, volutpat eget velit. Aenean quis vestibulum ante. Duis enim tortor, accumsan eget hendrerit non, pellentesque vel magna. Duis eros turpis, auctor vel aliquam vitae, congue ut dolor.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Sed a libero mi. Donec cursus dignissim quam tincidunt fermentum. Curabitur ac libero leo, non sagittis nisi. Proin sodales tincidunt ante, in aliquam justo cursus in. Nunc tempus feugiat volutpat. Phasellus porttitor dolor elementum quam suscipit tempus. Donec posuere consectetur turpis sed congue. Sed et nunc dui, sit amet viverra erat. Ut malesuada molestie quam, porta fringilla libero consequat quis.
\addtocounter{equation}{100}
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Nullam elementum libero ut erat suscipit cursus non eget nibh. In accumsan rhoncus scelerisque. Sed vel eros et lacus tincidunt laoreet. Etiam molestie metus id tortor euismod vitae bibendum nisi rhoncus.


Pellentesque nec gravida ligula. Curabitur nibh sem, porta in suscipit non, porttitor lobortis arcu. Sed imperdiet, nisi sit amet vehicula lobortis, eros urna aliquam magna, sed auctor sem dui nec turpis. Nulla facilisi. Nam a elit lacus. Etiam vel leo ligula. Donec lectus mi, tristique at lobortis id, viverra nec felis.
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Etiam vel felis at enim pulvinar lacinia lacinia quis ipsum. Etiam ac elementum tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque sit amet rhoncus tortor.
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      Ax = b
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}

Nullam sollicitudin nisl ac metus malesuada fermentum. Mauris tellus arcu, porttitor et condimentum ut, commodo pellentesque justo. Nam rutrum, nunc non dictum placerat, dolor metus interdum dui, eu tincidunt libero mauris vel ante.
\begin{equation}\label{b}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Nunc placerat auctor odio, vel ullamcorper massa dapibus eu. Suspendisse luctus, erat at semper pulvinar, velit diam convallis metus, vitae aliquam nibh tortor vitae neque. Morbi venenatis eleifend sapien at pulvinar. Quisque urna leo, molestie ut consequat id, porta vitae neque. Praesent varius convallis justo id tincidunt. Duis nulla elit, euismod sit amet tincidunt ut, sodales eu felis. Phasellus rutrum bibendum urna sit amet iaculis.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Nullam vel velit quis nibh volutpat ullamcorper. Pellentesque tempor turpis quis massa tincidunt imperdiet. Nam lobortis, justo quis mollis faucibus, erat enim lobortis massa, sagittis egestas lacus odio sed enim. Morbi pulvinar placerat sem, eget pulvinar risus hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed elementum faucibus mi, eget euismod magna convallis vel. Fusce egestas posuere dignissim.
\end{document}
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

This uses `\pdfsavepos` so it takes a couple of latex runs to settle down but it's more accurate than testing the value of the page counter which can be out due to the asynchronous nature of the output routine. This version just moves the number over it doesn't check for clashes, although mostly it won't overprint as amsmath will have moved the equation number down for large equations. (Arguably equation numbers on the left should move up, but this doesn't do that).

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,standard]{ntheorem}

\newcommand{\marginnote}[1]{\marginpar[\raggedleft#1]{\raggedright#1}}


\makeatletter

\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\leavevmode%
\pdfsavepos
\edef\tmp{\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\EQ@\romannumeral#1{{\noexpand\the\c@page}{\noexpand\the\pdflastxpos}}}}%
\tmp
\expandafter\ifx\csname EQ@\romannumeral#1\endcsname\relax
\else
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\foo\csname EQ@\romannumeral#1\endcsname{#1}%
\fi
}}

\def\foo#1#2#3{%
\ifodd\numexpr#1\relax
(\ignorespaces#3\unskip\@@italiccorr)%
\else
\kern1sp\llap{\rlap{(\ignorespaces#3\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\kern\textwidth}%
\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

TEST\clearpage


Integer suscipit massa et nulla accumsan sed lacinia lacus tincidunt. Aenean nisi lacus, iaculis eu consequat in, fermentum eget urna. Proin augue lacus, euismod eu tempor vel, mollis eget quam. Donec vitae consequat nulla. In cursus sagittis diam, at tristique sem interdum pharetra.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Morbi gravida dapibus dapibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris mauris diam, faucibus vitae pretium vitae, volutpat eget velit. Aenean quis vestibulum ante. Duis enim tortor, accumsan eget hendrerit non, pellentesque vel magna. Duis eros turpis, auctor vel aliquam vitae, congue ut dolor.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Sed a libero mi. Donec cursus dignissim quam tincidunt fermentum. Curabitur ac libero leo, non sagittis nisi. Proin sodales tincidunt ante, in aliquam justo cursus in. Nunc tempus feugiat volutpat. Phasellus porttitor dolor elementum quam suscipit tempus. Donec posuere consectetur turpis sed congue. Sed et nunc dui, sit amet viverra erat. Ut malesuada molestie quam, porta fringilla libero consequat quis.
\addtocounter{equation}{100}
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Nullam elementum libero ut erat suscipit cursus non eget nibh. In accumsan rhoncus scelerisque. Sed vel eros et lacus tincidunt laoreet. Etiam molestie metus id tortor euismod vitae bibendum nisi rhoncus.


Pellentesque nec gravida ligula. Curabitur nibh sem, porta in suscipit non, porttitor lobortis arcu. Sed imperdiet, nisi sit amet vehicula lobortis, eros urna aliquam magna, sed auctor sem dui nec turpis. Nulla facilisi. Nam a elit lacus. Etiam vel leo ligula. Donec lectus mi, tristique at lobortis id, viverra nec felis.
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Etiam vel felis at enim pulvinar lacinia lacinia quis ipsum. Etiam ac elementum tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque sit amet rhoncus tortor.
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      Ax = b
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}

Nullam sollicitudin nisl ac metus malesuada fermentum. Mauris tellus arcu, porttitor et condimentum ut, commodo pellentesque justo. Nam rutrum, nunc non dictum placerat, dolor metus interdum dui, eu tincidunt libero mauris vel ante.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Nunc placerat auctor odio, vel ullamcorper massa dapibus eu. Suspendisse luctus, erat at semper pulvinar, velit diam convallis metus, vitae aliquam nibh tortor vitae neque. Morbi venenatis eleifend sapien at pulvinar. Quisque urna leo, molestie ut consequat id, porta vitae neque. Praesent varius convallis justo id tincidunt. Duis nulla elit, euismod sit amet tincidunt ut, sodales eu felis. Phasellus rutrum bibendum urna sit amet iaculis.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Nullam vel velit quis nibh volutpat ullamcorper. Pellentesque tempor turpis quis massa tincidunt imperdiet. Nam lobortis, justo quis mollis faucibus, erat enim lobortis massa, sagittis egestas lacus odio sed enim. Morbi pulvinar placerat sem, eget pulvinar risus hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed elementum faucibus mi, eget euismod magna convallis vel. Fusce egestas posuere dignissim.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes you can combine this with the code from the question that is linked in this question, also (as in that answer) probably need to make \ref use the original formatting so in-text references to equation names don't fly off to the left, will look later.

Comment: code/image updated

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Does it look great? I still haven't decided...

Answer (score 14):

In the solution below I've borrowed code from

- [Equation tag in twoside-mode outer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/equation-tag-in-twoside-mode-outer)
- [Changing the appearance of equation numbers with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/changing-the-apperance-of-equation-numbers-with-amsmath)
- [Theorem Name/Numbering in Margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59244/theorem-name-numbering-in-margin/)

The part that does what you need is

```
% customize the tag form of the equations
\makeatletter
\global\tagsleft@true
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{%
\ifodd\value{page}
\maketag@@@{\hbox{\rlap{\hspace{.25cm}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\hspace{1mm}}}}\kern1sp%
\else
    \maketag@@@{\hbox{\llap{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\hspace{2mm}}}}\kern1sp%
\fi}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{{\mytagform@{\ref{#1}}}}

\EveryShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}% Test page number
      \global\@fleqntrue
  \else
      \global\@fleqnfalse
      \fi
}
```

I loaded the [`showframe`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/showframe) just to check that it was working. I manually tweaked the `hspace` to get the `tag` into the margin- no doubt this could be done using a length (wasn't sure what it is called).

The [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) package offers three choices for its equation alignment:

- `leqno`
- `reqno`
- `fleqn`

I was originally working with toggling `tagsleft@` between `true` and `false`; I don't know why that didn't work, but toggling `\@fleqn` to `true` or `false` did the job just fine.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,standard]{ntheorem}

\newcommand{\marginnote}[1]{\marginpar[\raggedleft#1]{\raggedright#1}}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% customize the tag form of the equations
\makeatletter
\global\tagsleft@true
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{%
\ifodd\value{page}
\maketag@@@{\hbox{\rlap{\hspace{.25cm}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\hspace{1mm}}}}\kern1sp%
\else
    \maketag@@@{\hbox{\llap{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\hspace{2mm}}}}\kern1sp%
\fi}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{{\mytagform@{\ref{#1}}}}

\EveryShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}% Test page number
      \global\@fleqntrue
  \else
      \global\@fleqnfalse
      \fi
}

\begin{document}

Integer suscipit massa et nulla accumsan sed lacinia lacus tincidunt. Aenean nisi lacus, iaculis eu consequat in, fermentum eget urna. Proin augue lacus, euismod eu tempor vel, mollis eget quam. Donec vitae consequat nulla. In cursus sagittis diam, at tristique sem interdum pharetra.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Morbi gravida dapibus dapibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris mauris diam, faucibus vitae pretium vitae, volutpat eget velit. Aenean quis vestibulum ante. Duis enim tortor, accumsan eget hendrerit non, pellentesque vel magna. Duis eros turpis, auctor vel aliquam vitae, congue ut dolor.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Sed a libero mi. Donec cursus dignissim quam tincidunt fermentum. Curabitur ac libero leo, non sagittis nisi. Proin sodales tincidunt ante, in aliquam justo cursus in. Nunc tempus feugiat volutpat. Phasellus porttitor dolor elementum quam suscipit tempus. Donec posuere consectetur turpis sed congue. Sed et nunc dui, sit amet viverra erat. Ut malesuada molestie quam, porta fringilla libero consequat quis.
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Nullam elementum libero ut erat suscipit cursus non eget nibh. In accumsan rhoncus scelerisque. Sed vel eros et lacus tincidunt laoreet. Etiam molestie metus id tortor euismod vitae bibendum nisi rhoncus.

Pellentesque nec gravida ligula. Curabitur nibh sem, porta in suscipit non, porttitor lobortis arcu. Sed imperdiet, nisi sit amet vehicula lobortis, eros urna aliquam magna, sed auctor sem dui nec turpis. Nulla facilisi. Nam a elit lacus. Etiam vel leo ligula. Donec lectus mi, tristique at lobortis id, viverra nec felis.
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Etiam vel felis at enim pulvinar lacinia lacinia quis ipsum. Etiam ac elementum tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque sit amet rhoncus tortor.
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      Ax = b
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}

Nullam sollicitudin nisl ac metus malesuada fermentum. Mauris tellus arcu, porttitor et condimentum ut, commodo pellentesque justo. Nam rutrum, nunc non dictum placerat, dolor metus interdum dui, eu tincidunt libero mauris vel ante.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Nunc placerat auctor odio, vel ullamcorper massa dapibus eu. Suspendisse luctus, erat at semper pulvinar, velit diam convallis metus, vitae aliquam nibh tortor vitae neque. Morbi venenatis eleifend sapien at pulvinar. Quisque urna leo, molestie ut consequat id, porta vitae neque. Praesent varius convallis justo id tincidunt. Duis nulla elit, euismod sit amet tincidunt ut, sodales eu felis. Phasellus rutrum bibendum urna sit amet iaculis.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Nullam vel velit quis nibh volutpat ullamcorper. Pellentesque tempor turpis quis massa tincidunt imperdiet. Nam lobortis, justo quis mollis faucibus, erat enim lobortis massa, sagittis egestas lacus odio sed enim. Morbi pulvinar placerat sem, eget pulvinar risus hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed elementum faucibus mi, eget euismod magna convallis vel. Fusce egestas posuere dignissim.

Integer suscipit massa et nulla accumsan sed lacinia lacus tincidunt. Aenean nisi lacus, iaculis eu consequat in, fermentum eget urna. Proin augue lacus, euismod eu tempor vel, mollis eget quam. Donec vitae consequat nulla. In cursus sagittis diam, at tristique sem interdum pharetra.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Morbi gravida dapibus dapibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris mauris diam, faucibus vitae pretium vitae, volutpat eget velit. Aenean quis vestibulum ante. Duis enim tortor, accumsan eget hendrerit non, pellentesque vel magna. Duis eros turpis, auctor vel aliquam vitae, congue ut dolor.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Sed a libero mi. Donec cursus dignissim quam tincidunt fermentum. Curabitur ac libero leo, non sagittis nisi. Proin sodales tincidunt ante, in aliquam justo cursus in. Nunc tempus feugiat volutpat. Phasellus porttitor dolor elementum quam suscipit tempus. Donec posuere consectetur turpis sed congue. Sed et nunc dui, sit amet viverra erat. Ut malesuada molestie quam, porta fringilla libero consequat quis.
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
Nullam elementum libero ut erat suscipit cursus non eget nibh. In accumsan rhoncus scelerisque. Sed vel eros et lacus tincidunt laoreet. Etiam molestie metus id tortor euismod vitae bibendum nisi rhoncus.

Pellentesque nec gravida ligula. Curabitur nibh sem, porta in suscipit non, porttitor lobortis arcu. Sed imperdiet, nisi sit amet vehicula lobortis, eros urna aliquam magna, sed auctor sem dui nec turpis. Nulla facilisi. Nam a elit lacus. Etiam vel leo ligula. Donec lectus mi, tristique at lobortis id, viverra nec felis.
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Etiam vel felis at enim pulvinar lacinia lacinia quis ipsum. Etiam ac elementum tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque sit amet rhoncus tortor.
\begin{theorem}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \begin{proof}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
    \begin{equation}
      Ax = b
    \end{equation}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus mi, pharetra eget sodales volutpat, aliquam eu metus. Aenean ultricies iaculis sapien, pretium lobortis ligula ultrices a.
  \end{proof}
\end{theorem}

Nullam sollicitudin nisl ac metus malesuada fermentum. Mauris tellus arcu, porttitor et condimentum ut, commodo pellentesque justo. Nam rutrum, nunc non dictum placerat, dolor metus interdum dui, eu tincidunt libero mauris vel ante.
\begin{equation}
  A = \{x_{i,j}: i = 1, \ldots, n; j = 1, \ldots, m\}
\end{equation}
Nunc placerat auctor odio, vel ullamcorper massa dapibus eu. Suspendisse luctus, erat at semper pulvinar, velit diam convallis metus, vitae aliquam nibh tortor vitae neque. Morbi venenatis eleifend sapien at pulvinar. Quisque urna leo, molestie ut consequat id, porta vitae neque. Praesent varius convallis justo id tincidunt. Duis nulla elit, euismod sit amet tincidunt ut, sodales eu felis. Phasellus rutrum bibendum urna sit amet iaculis.\marginnote{Margin text.}
\begin{equation}
  Ax = b
\end{equation}
Nullam vel velit quis nibh volutpat ullamcorper. Pellentesque tempor turpis quis massa tincidunt imperdiet. Nam lobortis, justo quis mollis faucibus, erat enim lobortis massa, sagittis egestas lacus odio sed enim. Morbi pulvinar placerat sem, eget pulvinar risus hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed elementum faucibus mi, eget euismod magna convallis vel. Fusce egestas posuere dignissim.
\end{document}
```

## Possible reasons to consider *not* doing this

When we read a document (in a Left-To-Right language) we train our eyes to look for chapter/section numbers, enumerated lists, and theorem-like environments on the *left* of the page. Imho, one of the reasons that tagging equations on the *right* of the page is effective is that equations are one of the only objects that do so.

Moving the equation tag to the left of the page may cause confusion to the reader as he/she may not be immediately clear that the equation tag does indeed belong to that equation.

Comment: @Audrey see the update- works fine in your MWE- let me know if you find another one that breaks it :)

Comment: Dammit! The example was still too minimal. It will likely take some time for me to find a better one. The existing one does point out one issue though - on outer-left pages, the equations are left-aligned, not centred. Remaining problems the example doesn't uncover are related to numbers near page breaks.

Comment: @Audrey ok, let me know when you have another MNWE :)

Comment: I've updated the example and passed along your bounty. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Audrey you're very kind, thank you very much :) Does David's solution resolve everything, or should I keep trying with your updated code?

Comment: It's the least I can do for putting together bad examples. I think David has solved it, but I'll wait to do more testing once he's had another look.