# Alternating equation numbers

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equation numbers in outer margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94768/equation-numbers-in-outer-margins)

Is there a way to put equation numbers to the outer edge of a two-sided document? Some kind of mixture of leqno and reqno which puts eq. numbers to the left on even pages and to the right on odd pages.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: This looks *very* similar to [equation-numbers-in-outer-margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94768/equation-numbers-in-outer-margins) The answer I gave there used the `memoir` class, but it works for the other document classes too. Please let us know if that answer resolves the issue, and then we would close this as a duplicate :)