# Span figure across margin and textbody in twoside: Assigning savebox locally

Tags: grouping

For `twoside`documents, I'd like my wide images and tables to span both the margin and the text. In my approach, I have created a command, which takes the input and stores in in a `save box`, measures its total height, and places in in a `minipage`in the margin. The `minipage` spans the width of the margin and the text body.

The reason I had to use a `savebox`was that, since I am placing a `minipage`in the margin, it takes 0 vertical space in the text body, so I need to measure the height of it and place a `vspace` in the text to shift the material that follows down accordingly to that height.

Now this works great for the first run, but as soon as I call the command again to place another wide image, I get an error. I understand why I get this error; I am trying to overwrite an existing `savebox`. I thought when writing the code that it would be saved only locally, not globally. Is there any way I could do that? Assign it locally, that is, or perhaps just delete it afterwards.

In the following MWE, commenting out the line will give the error.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, showframe}
\newlength\marginandtext
\addtolength{\marginandtext}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\marginandtext}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\marginandtext}{\marginparsep}
\newcommand{\leftsidefullwidth}[1]{%
    \newsavebox\mybox
    \newlength\myheight
    \newlength\mydepth
    \savebox\mybox{\noindent#1}
    \settoheight\myheight{\usebox\mybox}
    \settodepth\mydepth{\usebox\mybox}
    \addtolength{\myheight}{\mydepth}
    \marginpar{\begin{minipage}{\marginandtext}
    \usebox\mybox
    \end{minipage}}
    \vspace{\myheight}
}
\begin{document}
This page is left empty for this example, since it needs to be shown on left pages.
\clearpage
\leftsidefullwidth{\includegraphics[width=\marginandtext,height=6cm]{example-image-a}}
foo
%\leftsidefullwidth{\includegraphics[width=\marginandtext,height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are taking up space in teh text flow it would be more natural to use a normal float than a marginpar and just make the image as wide as you need and shift to the right or left so that it sticks into the margin space.

Comment: as for the actual question always have the `\newxxx` command at the top level, you do not need to allocate a new box each time, just allocate a box for your package and re-use that box each time. Also you _need_ `%`  the ends of all those lines or your command will generate spurious white space in the text.

Comment: really? I thought I checked that a while ago. Guess I was completely wrong here. Okey, I guess this was a really stupid question on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not need a box or measurement at all here as

```
\savebox\mybox{\noindent#1}
```

`\savebox` is a *horizontal* construct (like `\mbox`) so `\noindent` is a no-op and the box is the size of its contents. You know that size in advance as you have

```
[width=\marginandtext,height=6cm]
```

You should use a normal float not a marginpar, as the float takes space in the main text flow, then use `\makebox[\textwidth][l]{begin{minipage}{\marginandtext}}` on one side and `[r]` on the other.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wouldn't always know the size of the box (for instance a table), that was just for example images.

Comment: @runartrollet you could just use a scratch box (such as `0`) for local measurement, but actually you know the width in advance (`\marginandtext`) and you only need the height to correct for the misuse of \marginpar, if you used a normal float you wouldn't need that vspace correction.

Comment: Any way to dynamically set `[r]`and `[l]`in `\makebox[\textwidth][l]{begin{minipage}{\marginandtext}}`depending on odd/even pages?

Comment: @runartrollet I have an answer on site somewhere about page dependent formatting in floats I'll see if I can find....

Comment: @runartrollet this is probably more general than you need for just odd/even but... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118001/rotate-image-according-to-pagenumber/118012#118012

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to make much sense of that... I'll start a new question regarding it.