# How to style equation label and reference differently?

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, equations, bold

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the apperance of equation numbers with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/changing-the-apperance-of-equation-numbers-with-amsmath)

I need to be able to make the labels of equations bold, but at the same time I need the citations to those equations to have normal style in the rest of the text.

Here is what I tried:

```
\let\theoldequation\theequation 
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\textbf{\theoldequation}} % bold equation numbers
```

and this (using `etoolbox` package)

```
\pretocmd{\theequation}{\textbf}{}{}
```

Output:

[image]

To solve this, I googled a lot, and could only come up with the following trials:

```
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textnormal{(\ref{#1})}}
```

and

```
\let\oldeqref\eqref
\renewcommand*{\eqref}{\textnormal{\oldeqref}} % bold equation numbers
```

and

```
\pretocmd{\eqref}{\textnormal}{}{}
```

and the last one:

```
\patchcmd{\eqref}{\textbf}{\textnormal}{}{}
```

But none yielded what I am required to do. Can you give a solution to this problem?

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you for pointing out the other related question. With the last statement in that question added, mine looks pretty much like a duplicate. Even though I did a thorough search, it seems I had failed to find that. Should I do anything for this?

Comment: no harm done. You might approach one of the moderators in the chat room; I'll flag it for one of them to view

Comment: @cmhughes I've closed as a duplicate here as requested. I can merge if you want: that will move the answer here to the duplicate question, and this question will 'vanish'. We don't normally do that, as the OP then looses the rep they get from the question part. So I'm minded to leave this as-is.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for your consideration. I don't mind removing my question. Please feel free to take necessary actions. But this question seems to be more direct to the topic and could be useful. So I think, it might be left as-is as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using `amsmath` and `\eqref`, you need to redefine `\tagform@` and `\eqref` to have both the label and parentheses in bold face:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{{\normalfont(\ref{#1}}\normalfont)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a + b = c.
\end{equation}

See equation~\eqref{eq:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If only the label needs to be boldfaced, then you can say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces\textbf{#1}\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{{\normalfont(\ref{#1}}\normalfont)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a + b = c.
\end{equation}

See equation~\eqref{eq:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, it worked like a charm! I wish I could give up vote, need 4 to go. :)

Comment: @ciuncan there was a little mistake in the redefinitions, but now I've corrected it in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I saw the correction, and applied it. Went with your second code fragment.

Comment: The package `mathtools` offers a convenient user-command for this: `\newtagform{bold}[\textbf]{(}{)}\usetagform{bold}`

Answer (score 3):

Redefine `\@eqnnum`. (EDIT: As Torbjørn T. points out, this doesn't work if, as the OP, one uses `amsmath`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont\normalcolor\bfseries(\theequation)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

See equation~\ref{eq:test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Considering `\eqref`, the OP is perhaps using `amsmath`, in which case this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as @TorbjørnT. stated, unfortunately nothing changed. Is there an `amsmath' way to do this?