# Numbering equations in LaTeX with hearts instead of parenthesis

Tags: equations

Is it possible to encase numbers in hearts instead of parenthesis when my equations are enumerated?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I guess there are [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69358/how-to-style-equation-label-and-reference-differently) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/changing-the-apperance-of-equation-numbers-with-amsmath) that look like your problem. Personally I prefer `\newtagform` mentioned in one of comments the most.

Answer (score 3):

Set the equation's "tag form" using [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% \newtagform{<name>}{<left>}{<right>}
\newtagform{hearts}{$\heartsuit$}{$\heartsuit$}
\usetagform{hearts}

\begin{document}

See~\eqref{eq:abc}.
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eq:abc}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

Perhaps you might be interested in putting the number *inside* a heart:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,graphicx}

\newcommand{\enheart}[1]{%
  \smash{%
    \ooalign{%
      \scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-.2ex}{$\heartsuit$}}\cr
      \hidewidth\raisebox{.5ex}{\tiny #1}\hidewidth}}}
% \newtagform{<name>}[<inner>]{<left>}{<right>}
\newtagform{hearts}[\enheart]{}{}
\usetagform{hearts}

\begin{document}

See~\eqref{eq:abc}.
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eq:abc}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You'll have to shrink the number and enlarge the heart, which might cause problems with line-spacing (hence the `\smash`).

To switch back to the default, use `\usetagform{default}`.

Comment: I thought OP wants something like `\def\tagform@#1{~\lower5pt\clap{\Huge$\heartsuit$}\clap{#1}}`.