# Customize the way eqref works with tags

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, amsmath

I'd like to have a version of `\eqref` that treats equations with a custom tag differently from the usual numbered equation. In particular, if I assign a tag to an equation, I'd like `\eqref` not to put parens around the reference. Below is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:normal}
   a = b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:tagged}
   y = max\{1,x\} \tag{$P(x)$}
\end{equation}

Equations \eqref{eq:normal} will display as "(1)" (i.e., with parens)
and \eqeref{eq:tagged} will display as "$P(x)$" (i.e., without parens).

\end{document}
```

How would I modify the `\eqref` command?

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28894/86 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28903/86 useful to you?

Answer (score 8):

don't use `\eqref`.  just use `\ref`.  the main purpose of `\eqref` is to put parens around tags in accordance with ams style.  it also ensures that they're set in upright type, which is not done with `\ref`, so you may still want to apply `\upshape` or `\textup`, although that isn't a problem as long as you are explicitly treating the tag as math.

Addendum: you can just equate `\myeqref` to `\ref` so that references to the explicitly-tagged displays can easily be found:

```
\newcommand\myeqref[1]{\ref{#1}}
```

although it's possible to adapt the `amsmath` definition to do what you want, it's more than i have time to unravel just now, especially when there's a simpler approach.

Comment: The problem with this (straightforward) approach is that if in a later draft I change my mind, and wish to remove the custom tag and just have a numbered citation, I have to change every `\ref` to `\eqref`.

Comment: You can always do `\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\ref{#1}}`. Then if you change your mind, remove or comment this, or replace it with something else.

Comment: Herald: Wouldn't this unintentionally affect the way that `\eqref{eq:normal}` is displayed? My goal is only to change the way that `\eqref{eq:tagged}` is displayed.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Your code in the comment is missing a final }.