# How can I make \eqrefs clickable?

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath

I have modified the `\eqref` macro like this

```
\let\originaleqref\eqref
\renewcommand{\eqref}{equation~\originaleqref}
```

as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28896/31250). I want to have the reference be typeset like `equation x` or `equation (x)` and be completely clickable. This MWE illustrates what I want.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\let\originaleqref\eqref
\renewcommand{\eqref}{equation~\originaleqref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:some_eq}
   a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

I want to refer to \eqref{eq:some_eq}.
Using \verb+\eqref+ should produce \hyperref[eq:some_eq]{equation 1}.
\end{document}
```

The result
[image]

Is there a straightforward way to customise the typesetting of such references or do I need to completely redefine the `\eqref` macro?

Comment: Did you consider using `cleveref`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Egreg mentions, you can use `cleverref`, if you do not want to you can use something similar to this.We use the fact that `\ref*` (aka non-link ref) in `hyperref` is the macro `\@refstar`. Thus inside the new `\eqref` we make the link via `\hyperref[target]{text}` and make sure that `text` itself, does not contain any hyperrefs (as nested hyperlinks does not really make any sense)

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\let\originaleqref\eqref % or \let\originaleqref\ref to drop parens
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\ref\@refstar%
  \hyperref[#1]{%
    equation%
    ~\originaleqref{#1}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:some_eq}
   a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

I want to refer to \eqref{eq:some_eq}.
Using \verb+\eqref+ should produce \hyperref[eq:some_eq]{equation 1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: For compatibility with `IEEEeqnarray`, this seems to be the superior solution. How would I go about removing the parentheses, if I wanted?

Comment: Replace `\original\eqref` with `\ref` or `\ref*`, it is the original `\eqref` that adds the `()`'s. I'd say that I would not have it write `equation~num` each and every time I referred to an equation. Usually we just use the plain `\eqref` or an edited version that makes the entire `\eqref` into a hyperlink. BTW: if this is for a journal, then be careful with redefinitions. It might be that you rewrites/redefinitions is against the journal style, and thus might need to be removed later on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; it is not for a journal though.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by egreg, it's easy using `cleveref` (which must be loaded after `hyperref`).

Simply define

```
\crefformat{equation}{#2equation~#1#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~#1#3}
```

The arguments #2 and #3 are used to mark the beginning and end of the
part of the cross-reference that forms the hyperlink when the `hyperref` package is used.

Then simply use `\cref{eq:some_eq}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{equation}{#2equation~#1#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:some_eq}
   a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

I want to refer to \eqref{eq:some_eq}.
Using \verb+\eqref+ should produce \cref{eq:some_eq}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want `\eqref` to produce that output, simply add

```
\let\eqref\cref
```

and with this MWE

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{equation}{#2equation~#1#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~#1#3}
\let\eqref\cref


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:some_eq}
   a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

I want to refer to \eqref{eq:some_eq}.
Using \verb+\eqref+ should produce \eqref{eq:some_eq}.
\end{document}
```

you will obtain:

[image]

If you want instead the link to be `equation (1)` use

```
\crefformat{equation}{#2equation~(#1)#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~(#1)#3}
```

You can also modify the behavior for equation ranges with `\crefrangeformat` and `\Crefrangeformat`. Take a look at the `cleveref` manual for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, `cleveref` is incompatible with `eqnarray` and `IEEEeqnarray`, wich I use at many places.

Comment: @oarfish You really [shouldn't use `eqnarray`](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf)

Comment: @JuriRobl That's why I use `IEEEeqnarray`.