# How to label equation with particular format?

Tags: equations, numbering

I have several equations, I want to label equation 1 and 2 to be (eqt1) and (eqt2), any other equations after it use normal equation number, say (1), (2), (3),... How to do it in latex?

E.g.

```
\begin{align}
 1+1=2 (eqt1)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 2+3=5 (eqt2)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 3+3=6 (1)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 4+3=7 (2)
\end{align}
```

Comment: That's the work for `\tag{hello}`

Comment: please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28894/modify-eqref-command

Comment: @Yorgos We can straightaway achieve it with `\tag{...}` (which is part of `amsmath` package) to customise the `label` of equations and then use the normal way of cross-referencing the equations with `\eqref{...}`.

Comment: @Raaja oo nice... i didn't know this command, since i am using `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`

Comment: @Yorgos [Fun-fact] It is applicable for `mathtools` as well ;)

Comment: @Raaja :) (if i remember correctly, `mathtools` loads `amsmath`)

Comment: @Yorgos Yep, I think so too. :D

Comment: Don't use `align` as a substitute for `equation` when you have a one-line display.

Answer (score 6):

With `amsmath` package, you can achieve it with `tag` environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\label{e1}  1+1=2 \tag{eqt1}
    \end{align}

    \begin{align}
\label{e2}  2+3=5 \tag{eqt2}
    \end{align}

    \begin{align}
\label{e3}  3+3=6 
    \end{align}

    \begin{align}
\label{e4}  4+3=7 
    \end{align}
    I am referring \eqref{e1}, \eqref{e2}, \eqref{e3}, \eqref{e4}. 
\end{document}
```

Which would give you

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility, using the same equation counter as the default: `mathtools` has a `\newtagform` command, which can be used to customise the appearance of the equation number, and a `\usetagform` command which can be used within the document body:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{eqt}{(eqt\,}{)}

\begin{document}

\usetagform{eqt}
    \begin{align}
\label{e1} 1+1=2
    \end{align}

    \begin{align}
\label{e2} 2+3=5
    \end{align}

\usetagform{default}
    \begin{align}
\label{e3} 3+3=6
    \end{align}

    \begin{align}
\label{e4} 4+3=7
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP asked for `(eqt1), (eqt2), (1), (2)`. You have given them `(eqt1), (eqt2), (3), (4)`. You would need to reset the counter after `(eqt2)` to give the behaviour asked for

Comment: This was not quite clear to me. I indeed mentioned that in what I propose, both types of equation share the same counter – only the formatting differs.

Comment: They said they wanted to have `(eqt1)` and `(eqt2)` and then start counting from `(1)` again. Your answer continues counting after `(eqt2)` with `(3)` so you need to include `\setcounter{equation}{0}` at that point to get the behaviour the OP wanted